# .NET constant for number of seconds in a day?

Tags: .net, constants, seconds

Does .NET have a constant for the number of seconds in a day (86400)?

Comment: Why can't you specify your own? It's not likely to change any time soon...

Comment: Having seen the System.Net.WebRequestMethods.Http constants (ubiquitous, unchanging, and commonly used -- much like SECONDS_IN_A_DAY), it wouldn't have surprised me if .NET would have provided something here.

Comment: Yes, it's `86400`. Don't use it though, it's a bit buggy, and always returns the value 86400, regardless of leap seconds and locale.

Comment: @Rob Sanders: I'm writing a unit test which returns a number of seconds, and it dealt in days.

Comment: <3 SO.  The dialog on this question really made me rethink my approach.  I don't need a constant, now, and the code is cleaner and more durable for not having one.  DateTime and TimeSpan objects have given me everything I need, really.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want readability you could use:

```
(new TimeSpan(1,0,0,0)).TotalSeconds
```

though just using your own const might be clearer :)

Comment: Not a constant, but leaves me out of the second-counting business.

Comment: This simple answer made me rethink the approach I was taking.  It's not quite the code I used to ultimately solve my problem, but I'm all for choosing an answer based on the fishing it taught rather than the fish it provided.  Thank you.

Answer (score 21):

It's not a constant value

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_second

Comment: Leap seconds are not the only problem, days where daylight saving time changes occur have an hour less or more (counting from 00:00-24:00) in the according timezones.

Comment: Fortunately, in about 363/365 cases, 86400 is good enough.  ;)

Comment: @GaussZ: That is why you should always store times as UTC.

Comment: Leap seconds are however not used in the standard .NET DateTime representation.  So irrelevant for all except specialized applications.

Answer (score 6):

so much effort just for not defining a const for 60 x 60 x 24 ;)

Answer (score 5):

Number of seconds in a *regular* day is 86400. But the days when DST changes happen may be shorter or longer.

However, writing 24*60*60 is not a bad practice at all, and it is most likely to be in-lined by the compiler, too!

Answer (score 5):

```
double secondsPerDay = TimeSpan.FromDays(1).TotalSeconds;
```

This was a comment from @ckarras.  Adding it as an answer to make it more visible.

Answer (score 4):

closest your going to get w/o specifying you own:

```
System.TimeSpan.TicksPerDay / System.TimeSpan.TicksPerSecond
```

you could even wrap this as an extension method...

```
public static Extensions
{
   public static int SecondsPerDay( this System.TimeSpan ts )
   {
      return   System.TimeSpan.TicksPerDay / System.TimeSpan.TicksPerSecond
   }
}
```

Comment: i dont think this makes sense as an extension method.  Probably just a utility class imo

Answer (score 3):

It is actually available in the .NET framework.  You can get to it like this:

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;

public static class DateTimeHelpers {
  public static int GetSecondsPerDay() {
    object obj = typeof(DateTime).GetField("MillisPerDay", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static).GetValue(null);
    return (int)obj / 1000;
  }
}
```

Please don't use that.

Comment: Well, it shouldn't be.  It smoothly handles the .NET update required after the Earth's rotation slows down enough.

Answer (score 2):

It isn't a constant, the number of seconds in a day varies depending on the day and the timezone. Thus it isn't something that Microsoft is likely to offer.

Comment: you won't tell me that a day in arizona is not the same 24 hours long as it is in e.g. singapour?

Answer (score 0):

If you want a smidgen more readability than GaussZ's answer you could use:

```
TimeSpan.FromDays(1).TotalSeconds
```