# Getting number of seconds in a day

Tags: .net, datetime

I have a list of datetimes that have always hold the time midnight, and the number of seconds a website was considered "up" on that day.

I need to work out the percentage of "uptime", so I need to know exactly how many seconds are in that day. I was wondering if there is anything in .NET similar to DateTime.DaysInMonth(year, month) but for seconds in a day.

My Google-fu seems to have let me down, and all I can find is [.NET constant for number of seconds in a day?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2136428/784908) - but that doesn't take into account daylight savings.

I think it is as simple as

```
var secondsInDay = (startDay.AddDays(1) - startDay).TotalSeconds;
```

But I was wondering if this is correct (simple but not exhaustive tests indicate it is)?
Is there a more efficient way of calculating the number of seconds in a given day?

**Please note - This needs to take account of daylight saving hours**

Comment: I think you're overcomplicating things.  Why not KISS and just base it on UTC days?

Comment: This is for monitoring site statistics for hosted websites. We need to be able to promise 99.9% uptime

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a function that will do what you asked:

```
public int SecondsInDay(DateTime dateTime, string timeZoneId)
{
    var dt1 = dateTime.Date;
    var dt2 = dt1.AddDays(1);
    var zone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(timeZoneId);

    var dto1 = new DateTimeOffset(dt1, zone.GetUtcOffset(dt1));
    var dto2 = new DateTimeOffset(dt2, zone.GetUtcOffset(dt2));
    var seconds = (dto2 - dto1).TotalSeconds;

    return (int) seconds;
}
```

As an example:

```
int s = SecondsInDay(new DateTime(2013, 1, 1), "Central Standard Time");
// 86400

int s = SecondsInDay(new DateTime(2013, 3, 10), "Central Standard Time");
// 82800

int s = SecondsInDay(new DateTime(2013, 11, 3), "Central Standard Time");
// 90000
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to use `DateTimeOffset` and `TimeZoneInfo`. This [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546099.aspx) can help you, specifically the second code snippet at section *Comparisons and Arithmetic Operations with DateTimeOffset Values*.

You can see in that code that they are adding hours to a DateTimeOffset instance on a daylight savings day and the result take into account the time change.

**EDIT:** Code below is taken from the article mentioned above (the code doesn't do what you want but shows that `DateTimeOffset` used with `TimeZoneInfo` is considering daylight savings time:

```
    public static void Main()
   {
      DateTime generalTime = new DateTime(2008, 3, 9, 1, 30, 0);
      const string tzName = "Central Standard Time";
      TimeSpan twoAndAHalfHours = new TimeSpan(2, 30, 0);

      // Instantiate DateTimeOffset value to have correct CST offset 
      try
      {
         DateTimeOffset centralTime1 = new DateTimeOffset(generalTime, 
                    TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(tzName).GetUtcOffset(generalTime));

         // Add two and a half hours      
         DateTimeOffset centralTime2 = centralTime1.Add(twoAndAHalfHours);
         // Display result
         Console.WriteLine("{0} + {1} hours = {2}", centralTime1, 
                                                    twoAndAHalfHours.ToString(), 
                                                    centralTime2);  
      }
      catch (TimeZoneNotFoundException)
      {
         Console.WriteLine("Unable to retrieve Central Standard Time zone information.");
      }
   }

    // The example displays the following output to the console: 
    //    3/9/2008 1:30:00 AM -06:00 + 02:30:00 hours = 3/9/2008 4:00:00 AM -06:00
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

`TimeSpan.FromDays(1).TotalSeconds`

Unless of course you're trying to account for the seconds added and removed occasionally from a day to keep Earth precession in line with clocks

For daylight tracking you can check if your day is one of the two that are returned by

`TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone.GetDaylightChanges(2013)`

and add/remove the Delta

OR you can skip these shenanigans by always calculating your uptime based on past 24h instead of 1 day

Comment: I must admit, I haven't tried that. Does it take into account daylight savings? I haven't tried it because I don't see how it could know when daylight savings hours start/stop (i.e. some days have 23 hours in and some have 25)